# google cloud gsutil cp ResumableUploadAbortException: 408 Upload Client Broken Connection error

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am using gsutil cp to move a large file (around 40g) from local driver to gcs bucket. It worked well before, somehow now I keep getting “ResumableUploadAbortException: 408 Upload Client Broken Connection”. I tried to do the gsutil cp to move a small file and it works fine.

I put a -D in the command: gsutil -D cp, here is the trace i got:

```
DEBUG: Exception stack trace:iB]   80.0 MiB/s                                   
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/test/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/gcs_json_api.py", line 1592, in _PerformResumableUpload
        additional_headers=addl_headers)
      File "/home/test/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/apitools/apitools/base/py/transfer.py", line 1013, in StreamMedia
        additional_headers=additional_headers, use_chunks=False)
      File "/home/test/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/apitools/apitools/base/py/transfer.py", line 968, in __StreamMedia
        raise exceptions.HttpError.FromResponse(response)
    apitools.base.py.exceptions.HttpError: HttpError accessing <https://storage.googleapis.com/resumable/upload/storage/v1/b/charleszhan-dss-playground-bucket/o?alt=json&fields=etag%2Cgeneration%2Cmd5Hash%2Csize%2CcustomerEncryption%2Ccrc32c&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AAANsUlrnIDRqoTNIeFM87J5TpvSOiKlxr-kfWMkYG0sO1qocki09C773h-z1V_JPAJ_jFGMyk-3fi7z35uf8-_ZsWBE8svx7w>: response: <{'x-guploader-uploadid': 'AAANsUlrnIDRqoTNIeFM87J5TpvSOiKlxr-kfWMkYG0sO1qocki09C773h-z1V_JPAJ_jFGMyk-3fi7z35uf8-_ZsWBE8svx7w', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Fri, 07 Aug 2020 15:28:34 GMT', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin', 'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate', 'expires': 'Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 'content-length': '251', 'server': 'UploadServer', 'alt-svc': 'h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"', 'status': '408'}>, content <{
      "error": {
        "code": 408,
        "message": "Upload Client Broken Connection",
        "errors": [
          {
            "message": "Upload Client Broken Connection",
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "uploadBrokenConnection"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    >
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/test/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/__main__.py", line 633, in _RunNamedCommandAndHandleExceptions
        user_project=user_project)
      File "/home/test/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/command_runner.py", line 411, in RunNamedCommand
        return_code = command_inst.RunCommand()
      File "/home/test/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/commands/cp.py", line 1195, in RunCommand
        seek_ahead_iterator=seek_ahead_iterator)
      File "/home/test/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/command.py", line 1515, in Apply
        arg_checker, should_return_results, fail_on_error)
      File "/home/test/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/command.py", line 1586, in _SequentialApply
        worker_thread.PerformTask(task, self)
      File "/home/test/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/command.py", line 2306, in PerformTask
        results = task.func(cls, task.args, thread_state=self.thread_gsutil_api)
      File "/home/test/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/commands/cp.py", line 780, in _CopyFuncWrapper
        preserve_posix=cls.preserve_posix_attrs)
      File "/home/test/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/commands/cp.py", line 995, in CopyFunc
        preserve_posix=preserve_posix)
      File "/home/test/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/utils/copy_helper.py", line 3928, in PerformCopy
        gzip_encoded=gzip_encoded)
      File "/home/test/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/utils/copy_helper.py", line 2220, in _UploadFileToObject
        parallel_composite_upload, logger)
      File "/home/test/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/utils/copy_helper.py", line 2036, in _DelegateUploadFileToObject
        elapsed_time, uploaded_object = upload_delegate()
      File "/home/test/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/utils/copy_helper.py", line 2209, in CallResumableUpload
        gzip_encoded=gzip_encoded_file)
      File "/home/test/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/utils/copy_helper.py", line 1837, in _UploadFileToObjectResumable
        gzip_encoded=gzip_encoded)
      File "/home/test/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/cloud_api_delegator.py", line 421, in UploadObjectResumable
        gzip_encoded=gzip_encoded)
      File "/home/test/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/gcs_json_api.py", line 1734, in UploadObjectResumable
        gzip_encoded=gzip_encoded)
      File "/home/test/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/gcs_json_api.py", line 1517, in _UploadObject
        additional_headers, progress_callback, gzip_encoded)
      File "/home/test/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/gcs_json_api.py", line 1655, in _PerformResumableUpload
        raise resumable_ex
    gslib.cloud_api.ResumableUploadAbortException: ResumableUploadAbortException: 408 Upload Client Broken Connection
```

Comment: What is your charging speed? And how long do you estimate it will take your server to upload 40GB in a bucket?, this is because in this [github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/368) is mentioned that `a week is the maximum lifetime for an ongoing upload`

Comment: takes about half an hour at most. The error always happen when all the data was uploaded and it is trying to perform md5 check.

Comment: Thanks for the logs this looks like an issue on the Google Cloud Storage backend, I recommend you, open a [public issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)

Answer (score 1):

`gsutil` automatically performs a resumable upload whenever you use the cp command to upload an object that is larger than 8 MiB. You do not need to specify any special command line options to make this happen. If your upload is interrupted, you can restart the upload by running the same cp command that you used to start the upload. Until the upload has completed successfully, it is not visible at the destination object and does not replace any existing object the upload is intended to overwrite.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you take a look at the error trace I just added in my post ? The error always happen when all the data was uploaded and it is trying to perform some check